# SpringBoot with Aws postgress

Tags: spring, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, hibernate

I am creating a project Java Springboot with postgreSql connected to AWS

An error:
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Aug 13 10:46:24 UTC 2021
[a93e3797-1] There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

UserController:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private userService userService;
    private static final String ERROR_MAPPING = "/error";


    @PostMapping(path="/employees")
    public customers addEmployee(@RequestBody customers employee) {
        return userService.save(employee);
    }


    @GetMapping(path="/employees")
    public ResponseEntity<List<customers>> getAllEmployees() {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.listAll());
    }


}
```

User Service:

```
@Service
public class userService {

    @Autowired
    private userRepository repo;

    public List<customers> listAll(){
        return repo.findAll();

    }

    public customers save(customers u) {
        repo.save(u);
        return u;
    }


}
```

User Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface userRepository extends JpaRepository<customers, Long> {
}
```

User Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class customers {

    private int Customer_Id;
    private String First_Name;
    private String Last_Name;
    private int Phone_Number;


 public customers(int customer_Id, String first_Name, String last_Name, int phone_Number) {
        Customer_Id = customer_Id;
        First_Name = first_Name;
        Last_Name = last_Name;
        Phone_Number = phone_Number;
    }

    public customers() {
    }

    public int getCustomer_Id() {
        return Customer_Id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_Id(int customer_Id) {
        Customer_Id = customer_Id;
    }

    public String getFirst_Name() {
        return First_Name;
    }

    public void setFirst_Name(String first_Name) {
        First_Name = first_Name;
    }

    public String getLast_Name() {
        return Last_Name;
    }

    public void setLast_Name(String last_Name) {
        Last_Name = last_Name;
    }

    public int getPhone_Number() {
        return Phone_Number;
    }

    public void setPhone_Number(int phone_Number) {
        Phone_Number = phone_Number;
    }
}
```

Application:package com.esdt.user;

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.esdt.user.model.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.esdt.user.repository.*")
@ComponentScan(basePackages={ "com.esdt.user.controller.*", "com.esdt.user.service.*" })
public class UserApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

properties:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://awswebsite/postgres?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
```

Comment: How does the url which you are hitting looks like? You copied error but you didn't say how you triggered it

Comment: I am using the public IPV4 : http://ec2-18-191-138-44.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080

Comment: ok, but you don't have mapping for home page, but for "/employees" so you need to call ec2-18-191-138-44.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/employees

Comment: I tried with /employees but the same error

Comment: try without ":8080"

Comment: without :8080, error: This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following and it works:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>

<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```